# How can I create two KMS keys with the same material to do encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I am using KMS to encrypt/decrypt data (s3 object and string value). The data I encrypted is the file saved in s3 bucket. And some string values saved in database.

As an example, I use below command to encrypt the string value.

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id 59c41ce0-153b-487c-821b-7c1d994fca0c --plaintext QTEyMzQtMTIzNDU2WFk=
```

The key I created is a single region key. It is custom managed key and I use external origin and I have imported the key material to the KMS. Now I need to deploy my application in another region which means I need to decrypt the existing data from the other region.

The problem I have is that AWS doesn't support converting a single region key to multiple region. That means I have to re-create a new multiple region key. I own the key material and I expect I can import the same key material to the new multi-region key, then use this key to decrypt the existing data which was encrypted by the single region key.

But I got this error when I try to decrypt: `An error occurred (IncorrectKeyException) when calling the Decrypt operation: The key ID in the request does not identify a CMK that can perform this operation.`.

It seems there are other data used by kms to encrypt the data besides key material. Is there a way to replicate the key with same material? I expect I am able to re-create the kms with the same material to decrypt the data.

Comment: Encrypt decrypt how? Data keys? You have to explain exactly what you are doing.

Comment: The data I encrypted is the file saved in s3 bucket. And some string values saved in database

Comment: How do you then decrypt in other region?

Comment: use `aws kms encrypt` command to decrypt it from the other region by using the key in the other region as well.